# Android Consent Popup UMP SDK won't show popup

Tags: android, admob, gdprconsentform

I'm struggling to make the UMP SDK Consent Popup to show up, it's simply impossible or I'm doing somethig wrong, this is my code:

```
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        initializeAdsConsentPopup();
    }

    private void initializeAdsConsentPopup() {
        //I've also added my adMobAppID in my manifest.xml which matches the one below
 
        ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters
                .Builder()
                .setAdMobAppId("XXXXXXXXXXX")
                .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(SettingsPreferencesHelper.isUnderAge(this))
                .build();

        consentInformation = UserMessagingPlatform.getConsentInformation(this);
        //consentInformation.reset(); Tried using this before the call but it doesnt work.
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(
                this,
                params,
                () -> {
                    // The consent information state was updated.
                    // You are now ready to check if a form is available.
                    if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable()) {
                        loadForm();
                    } else {
                        warpToMainActivity();
                    }
                },
                formError -> {
                    // Handle the error.
                    Toast.makeText(this, formError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                });
    }

    public void loadForm() {
        // Loads a consent form. Must be called on the main thread.
        UserMessagingPlatform.loadConsentForm(
                this,
                consentForm -> {
                    this.consentForm = consentForm;
                    if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED) {
                        consentForm.show(
                                LegalConsentsActivity.this,
                                formError -> {
                                    if (consentInformation.getConsentStatus() == ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.OBTAINED) {
                                        warpToMainActivity();
                                    }
                                }); 
                    }
                },
                formError -> {
                    // Handle Error.
                    Toast.makeText(this, formError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        );
    }
```

Observations:

The call of `if (consentInformation.isConsentFormAvailable())` always return `false` and the status is always 3, which means OBTAINED:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface ConsentStatus {
    int UNKNOWN = 0;
    int NOT_REQUIRED = 1;
    int REQUIRED = 2;
    int OBTAINED = 3;
}
```

I've already fulfilled the AdMob Consent Message form and everything is setup, however the message simply doesn't show. I've tried adding the Phone ID Hash to To Debug Options:

```
   ConsentDebugSettings debugSettings = new ConsentDebugSettings.Builder(this)
                .setDebugGeography(ConsentDebugSettings.DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA)
                .addTestDeviceHashedId("51234512312321312345412")
                .build();
```

But it doesn't work too, same status code like before.

I've also tried to upload it to play store as a firmed .aab and it doesn't show the Popup.

I feel very lost right now, I've read the documentation and I've tried everything and I simply cannot make this work, any hint?

Answer (score 0):

UMP SDK is updated to new version check out latest implementation
here is simple example to show consent form and then banner
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/main/java/admob/BannerExample